# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File does not exist:

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write the Python in Sublime Text. Python 3 in Mac.

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r'\Users⁩\myxxxgmail.com⁩\Desktop\test.csv',encoding="utf-8")
```

Got an error:

> b'\Users\xe2\x81\xa9\myxxxgmail.com\xe2\x81\xa9\Desktop\test.csv' does not exist:

File test.csv actually exists in the directory.

If I remove the "r" before directory, codes:

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('\Users⁩\myxxxgmail.com⁩\Desktop\test.csv',encoding="utf-8")
```

Got an error:

> (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Same errors if removing the session encoding="utf-8".
How to fix this?

Comment: Your error message has a b before the string, not an r. Does the error occur with an r?

Comment: @ArturSiepietowski the header isn't relevant here as the interpreter can't even find the file. The error points to a problem with the requested file path.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the backslashes with forward slashes on the Mac and in Linux/UNIX ('posix' operating systems). Use backslash for Windows.

If you are writing code that should be compliant with either Windows or Mac/Linux/UNIX, import the `os` module and check the value of `os.name` - then adjust your path syntax appropriately.

Comment: or use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)